# nav-content materialize

Tags: html, css, angularjs-2.0, typescript, materialize

Buenos días
Estoy utilizando Angular2 con materialize, y en mi html tengo un navbar class="nav-content"
He podido ir modificando el estilo, pero no logro modificar el color de la linea indicadora de la pestaña activa.

```html
<nav class="yellow lighten-4">
  <div class="nav-content">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
      <li class="tab"><a routerLink="/inicio" class="blue-text text-darken-2">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a routerLink="/temas" class="blue-text text-darken-4">Temas</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a routerLink="/nuevo">Nuevo</a></li>
      <li class="tab disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: La linea blanca, me gustaria cambiarla de color pero no encuentro nada]

Answer (score 0):

tenía el mismo problema, modifiqué el color de la linea en materialize.min.css en la linea **3902**, y te sale esto:

```
.tabs .indicator {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
height:2px;
background-color:AQUI CAMBIAS EL COLOR;
will-change:left, right
}
```

Con eso tienes el problema solucionado, saludos